# How do I translate tidyverse from R into pandas from Python?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am conducting a data analysis in both R and Python to compare their differences. Currently I am struggling to translate

```
data %>%
  mutate(pct_leader = ballotsLeader/validBallots) %>%
  group_by(community) %>%
  mutate(mean_pct_leader = mean(pct_leader),
         sd_pct_leader = sd(pct_leader),
         up_pct_leader = mean_pct_leader+2*sd_pct_leader) %>%
  filter(pct_leader > up_pct_leader) %>%
  top_n(5, pct_leader)
```

into Python.

I have tried the following python code

```
grouped = data.assign(pct_leader = lambda x: x['ballotsLeader']/x['validBallots']).groupby('community').assign(mean_pct_leader = lambda x: mean(x['pct_leader']),
           sd_pct_leader = lambda x: stdev(x['pct_leader']),
           up_pct_leader = lambda x: x['mean_pct_leader']+2*x['sd_pct_leader']).query('pct_leader > up_pct_leader').pct_leader.nlargest(5)
```

but get a `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'assign'` error.

I realize this is because the DataFrameGroupBy object does not have the assign method.

How can preserve the order of the R code but translate it into python?

Edit: Here is the data I am working with

```
| community | province  | municipality | precinct | registeredVoters | emptyBallots | invalidBallots | validBallots | ballotsLeader |
|-----------|-----------|--------------|----------|------------------|--------------|----------------|--------------|---------------|
| GALICIA   | Coruña, A | Ames         | 001 B    | 270              | 3            | 7              | 206          | 129           |
| GALICIA   | Coruña, A | Ames         | 004 A    | 356              | 2            | 7              | 257          | 136           |
| GALICIA   | Coruña, A | Ames         | 002 C    | 296              | 1            | 2              | 214          | 149           |
| GALICIA   | Coruña, A | Ames         | 010 U    | 646              | 15           | 10             | 507          | 189           |
| GALICIA   | Coruña, A | Ames         | 012 B    | 695              | 6            | 8              | 479          | 247           |
```

Comment: kindly share a sample dataset; besides, there is no assign attribute for ``groupby`` as the error indicates.  possibly ``agg`` instead of assign, and pass a tuple of your arguments and aggregation function

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing some data, it's hard to have this correct, but this should work:

```
(data.assign(pct_leader=data['ballotsLeader'] / data['validBallots'])
 .groupby('community').agg(
     mean_pct_leader=('pct_leader', 'mean')
     sd_pct_leader=('pct_leader', 'std'),
     up_pct_leader=('pct_leader', lambda x: (x['pct_leader'].mean()+2) * x['pct_leader'].std())
 )
 .query('pct_leader > up_pct_leader')
 .nlargest(5, 'pct_leader')
)
```

Comment: This is helpful because it also translates `filter` to `.query` and `top_n` to `.nlargest`

Comment: I have added data to the question. Additionally, the solution you've supplied gets a key error on 'pct_leader'

Answer (score 1):

Using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), it will be easy for you to translate your R code into python:

```py
from datar.all import f, mutate, group_by, mean, sd, filter, slice_max

data >> \
  mutate(pct_leader = f.ballotsLeader/f.validBallots) >> \
  group_by(f.community) >> \
  mutate(mean_pct_leader = mean(f.pct_leader),
         sd_pct_leader = sd(f.pct_leader),
         up_pct_leader = f.mean_pct_leader+2*f.sd_pct_leader) >> \
  filter(f.pct_leader > f.up_pct_leader) >> \
  slice_max(f.pct_leader, n=5) 
  # top_n() has been superseded in favour of slice_min()/slice_max()
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.